# How to teleport someone and change their gamemode with a command block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm attempting to make an area on my server, where you can play in survival.  I don't want people to go there in creative, so I want to change their gamemode with the same block or button click as the teleporting one.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? In any SE site, we expect you to try first. Then, post what went wrong and well be more than glad to help you.

Comment: [Here is the wiki on command blocks](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Command_Block).  It is a good read if you are going to be dealing with command blocks.  I recommend the section on chained execution.

Answer (score 1):

the orange(impulse) command block is set on `needs redstone`and the green(chain) command block is set on `always active`
The Command In the 1st Command Block is: `gamemode 0 @p`
The Command In the 2nd Command Block is: `tp @p **the coördinates you want them to teleport to**`

This is very very basic. You better try out some things by yourself. I'm 13 and I work with these things for like 4 years, and I also just started by the `/tp` command. Now I make projects with over 300 command blocks. Just try some things out at youself and use the **minecraft wiki** to help you. Even I learn new things every day. The project you see in the background is also just a project for a working sniper. It's fun if you can create everything you want you should really learn command block coding yourself!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Behind the button, put a redstone current that powers a repeater pointing to a command  block. In that command block, do /gamemode 0, and start another redstone current from behind that command block. Same thing, put a repeater powered by that current pointing to a command block and do /tp @p [coordinates]. That way it will set the player's gamemode to survival, then teleport it to the destination.

Comment: It is recommended not to mix redstone and command blocks.  In the case of this answer, you can avoid all redstone by using [chained execution](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Command_Block#Chained_execution) since it is advising the use of two command blocks anyway.